# MIT Open Course Ware - Parametric Equations Problems

Tags: calculus, parametric, arc-length

The questions are the following:

1.Find the length of the curve $y =(e^x + e^{-x})/2$ for 0 ≤ x ≤ b. Hint:

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{e^{x} -e^{-x}}{2}\right)^{2} +1=\left(\frac{e^{x} +e^{-x}}{2}\right)^{2}
\end{equation}

2.Find an integral for the length of the curve given parametrically in Exercise 1 for 1 ≤ t ≤ 2. Simplify the integrand as much as possible but do not evaluate.

The answers given by the professor are:

1.$
\begin{equation*}
y'=\frac{e^{x} -e^{-x}}{2}
\end{equation*}$, so the hint says $1+(y')^2=y^2$ and $ds=\sqrt{1+( y')^{2}} \ dx=ydx$. Thus,

\begin{equation}
Arclength=\frac{1}{2}\int ^{b}_{0}\left( e^{x} +e^{-x}\right) dx=\frac{e^{b} -e^{-b}}{2}
\end{equation}

2.$dx/dt =1 − 1/t^2, dy/dt=1+1/t^2$. Thus

\begin{equation}
ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^{2}} dt=\sqrt{2+\frac{2}{t^{4}}} \ dt
\end{equation} and

\begin{equation}
Arclength=\frac{1}{2}\int ^{2}_{1}\sqrt{2+\frac{2}{t^{4}}} \ dt
\end{equation}

I don´t understand why from $1+(y')^2 = y^2$, it can be deduced that $ds=\sqrt{1+( y')^{2}} \ dx=ydx$. I neither understand where this conclusion, $dx/dt =1 − 1/t2, dy/dt=1+1/t^2$, comes from.

Comment: the fact that "$ds = \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$" is *not* being deduced from $1+y'^2 = y^2$. That's just the normal arc length formula.

Comment: $y= \cosh x,\; y'= \sinh x \;$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short justification for the arc length formula:

Given a parametric curve $\mathbf{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ the arc length formula between two times $t_1$ and $t_2$ is
$$s=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{\dot{x}(t)^2+\dot{y}(t)^2}~\mathrm{d}t$$
Why? Well the physical interpretation is this - the distance that a particle covers is simply the speed multiplied by the amount of time. The *velocity* of the particle is the time derivative of its position vector, that is, $\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)=(\dot{x}(t),\dot{y}(t)).$ The *speed* of the particle is the magnitude of this velocity vector, that is $\Vert\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)\Vert=\sqrt{\dot{x}(t)^2+\dot{y}(t)^2}$. In the special case that the path of the particle follows a trajectory where the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are related by some equation $y=f(x)$, one can use the parameterization $x=t~;~y=f(t)$ to obtain
$$s=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(t)\right)^2+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f(t)\right)^2}~\mathrm{d}t$$
Taking the derivatives and noting that $t_1=x_1$ and $t_2=x_2$,
$$s=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2}~\mathrm{d}t$$
Let $f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and use the fact that $t=x$,
$$s=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}~\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Thank you, now, where dx/dt=1-1/t^2 and dy/dt=1+1/t^2 comes from?

Comment: @Nicolas1203 Not sure. Could you put a reference to your professor's notes in your question?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-4-techniques-of-integration/part-c-parametric-equations-and-polar-coordinates/problem-set-11/ - Section 4F - Exercise 5 - Solution

Comment: @Nicolas1203 You need to read the problem. It says use the equations in problem 4E-2, not 4F-2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I didn´t notice that detail.